# Regular Expressions: Get subdomain and domain

Tags: regex, nginx

In nginx, I have a line that states `~^(www\.)(?<sub>.+).(?<domain>.+)$`.

How do I make it so I can get the subdomain and domain be separate?  Like subdomain.example.com.

EDIT:
I tried `~^(www\.)?(?<sub>)\.?(?<domain>.+)$` and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape `.`

```
~^(www\.)?(?<sub>.+?)\.(?<domain>.+)$
```

Comment: can you provide some sample input and outputs?

Comment: Okay...  It is supposed to receive in a domain of `something.example.com` and it needs to get the `something` and the `example.com` in two separate variables (PCRE)

Comment: Always starts with www? eg: `www.something.example.com`

Comment: Sometimes starts with **www.**, but not always.

Comment: We're getting closer.  domain was com and sub was something.example.

Comment: It should match as expected.. are you using the same? See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/fD3hR1/1)

Comment: Forgot a `?` and that's what screwed it up.  I gave you the cool green checkmark of coolness.